# Jquery preload values in input text and updating them

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have these text inputs in which they are preloaded with the user information on document load. My input html is as below

```
<div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="first_name">First Name</label>
     <div class="controls">
         <input type="text" class="account" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
     </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
     <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="account" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
     </div>
</div>
```

My preload is like this in jquery, in which it does a $.post to a php function. This works fine as the input elements are filled correctly.

```
function loadUserInfo()
{
    $.post('../accounts/load_user_info_ajax', null, function(data) {
        console.log(data.message);//Test to return user id

        var user = data.message;

        $('#inputEmail').val(user.email);
        $('#first_name').val(user.name);

    }, 'json');
}
```

However there is a update btn in which when I click on, it sends a $.post to another function. The jquery is as below

```
$('.update').on('click',function(){

    var type = $(this).attr('id');

    if(type == "account")
    {
        postvars = {
                name:$('#first_name').val(),
                email : $('#inputEmail').val(),
            };
        url = '../accounts/update_user_account_ajax';
    }

    $.post(url, postvars, function(data) {

        console.log(data);//Test to return user id
        alert(data.message);
        var user = data.message;

    }, 'json');
});
```

For a start I just return

```
function update_user_account_ajax()
{
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

       echo json_encode("test");
    }else {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

But nothing happens and I cannot see anything from chrome debugger network as well. The page refreshes as well and appends a ? to the ur. Thanks in advance for the help. I am using codeigniter for my php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Joel_Blum said, and also do this:
you should add `return false;` at the end of the body of the function `on('click',function(){ ...` to prevent reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
url :  '<?php echo site_url("accounts/update_user_account_ajax")?>
```